# Is there a way to kill all processes that are running in/from a certain directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill-process, working-directory

I need a way to kill everything that are running in the current directory. I'm somewhat new to shell, so forgive me for being stupid or potentially not understanding your answers. I have a half-decent grasp, but if you'd please take the extra time to explain what exactly your solution to my problem does, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `lsof` to list them.

Comment: Is there a way to kill them though, or set the processes as variables?

Comment: BTW -- if your goal here is to kill a process and all its children, personally, I would create and use an explicit lockfile. That is, `exec 3>file.lck` before starting your program, and then `fuser file.lck` to identify anything using it later. Whether `fuser` treats presence in a directory as having a handle on the directory isn't well-specified by POSIX, and various a little between operating systems. (Works on MacOS, but my testing hasn't been comprehensive).

Comment: ...though if your goal is heavy-duty process supervision, the Right Thing is to use something your OS provides. If you're on Linux, for example, something like systemd that can leverage cgroups is going to do a much better job of being able to provide per-process-tree quotas, control and management.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is specific to game servers. I'd like to have a script that can just kill all the processes running in the root dir of every game server, regardless of format.

Comment: That certainly sounds to me like a situation where the right tool for the job is a process supervision framework. Supervising your servers means they'll be automatically restarted when they fail (if you want them to be), and that you get very consistent tools for controlling if/when they're running, as what users, with what permissions, with what memory constraints, etc.

Comment: and if you want to be able to, say, `systemctl stop minecraft@*` (to stop all of them), or `systemctl stop minecraft@foobar` (to stop only the foobar instance), or `journalctl -u minecraft@foobar` (to see logs for the foobar instance), or so forth... well, most operating systems will give you either exactly those tools or ones very much like them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're probably right. Now that you mention it, this is a sort of hacky, inefficient way of going about it. What I'm trying to do specifically is check for game updates at regular intervals, kill the servers if there is one, update them, then start them again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `lsof` command then the argument will be the directory you want to kill the process

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                 
lsof $(pwd) | \                                                           
    awk -F " " ' { print $2 } ' | \                                       
    while read process ; do                                               
       [[ ${process} == "PID" ]] && continue;
          # kill the processes here
          # if you assign each process to a variable or an array
          # you will not be able to access it after leaving this while loop
          # pipes are executed as subshells
          echo ${process};                                                 
     done
```

Comment: Why roll your own rather than use `fuser -k`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy am not fluent with most linux commands, thanks, now i know this one exists

Comment: (btw, better to use `"$PWD"` -- more efficient *and* correct than `$(pwd)`).

Comment: @0.sh - actually, the `fuser` command is part of [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fuser.html), so it's way more than just a linux command. As you learn, bear in mind that the world is more than just Linux. When you write tools, consider whether you want to make the effort to make them portable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - "yes" in general, but the `$PWD` variable can be overwritten, which might lead to unexpected results if someone turned this into a function rather than running it as a standalone script.

Comment: @ghoti, true. OTOH, if we're looking at bizarre corner cases, even `"$(pwd)"` (with the missing quotes added, and thus no longer string-split and glob-expanded) is subject to trailing newlines being stripped as a side effect of command substitution -- if you have a directory created with `mkdir $'foo\n'`, it doesn't help to have that location read back as `foo`.

Comment: (If it wouldn't make me sound like such a hypocrite for taking a consistent hard line about programs that can't correctly handle unusual-but-legal filenames being buggy, I'd also be tempted to argue that folks who ignore POSIX guidance to stick to names with lower-case characters for application-defined variables deserve what they get).

Comment: @0.sh Could I replace { print $2 } with { print $(pwd) } to specify current dir?

Comment: @yea no. the current directory was already specified as an argument to `lsof`, `print $2` only gets the location of the `PIDs`

Comment: Could I use $(pwd) as an argument then?

Comment: argument to what ?

Comment: @yea, `$(pwd)` is already being passed an argument to `lsof`. You don't need to pass it to `awk` again later. (You *do* need to change it to `"$(pwd)"` or `"$PWD"` or else it won't work when you're in a directory with spaces in its name).

Comment: @0.sh Scratch that. How do I go about killing the processes?

Comment: `kill -9 ${process}` 9 is just a kill signal , you can use any kill signal you want , to get the list of kill signal type `kill -l` from your terminal

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'running in' a directory might be interpreted in different ways, some of them are:
(1) the program was started from this directory,
(2) the program uses this directory as working directory, or
(3) the program accesses this directory in any way.

Most likely you have problem (3) and the answer was already given: use

$ fuser -k

but beware, it might kill more than expected!

For problem (1) I would search the processes environment

$ grep -l "/home/username/directory" /proc/*/environ | grep -o [0-9]*

and kill the resulting processes.

Answer (score 0):

`lsof /path/to/directory | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill`

The `lsof /path/to/dir` command lists processes running in relation to the path. You can run this command alone on the shell to see for yourself.

The `awk '{ print $2 }'` part, weeds out only the PID of those processes

The `xargs` helps arrange the PID list into a horizontal list and then hand it over to the kill command.